# SQL Server database backup file cannot restore

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

In SQL Server 2008, I have a database which exceeds 10GB in size. I cleaned up the database and took a backup from it. Backup file size is 160MB.

Once I try to restore this backup file to SQL Server 2008 R2, an error popups.

[image: error]

I have already done this process earlier with same server-different database.
But that database size was smaller.

Please help me to restore database.

Comment: It seems you're trying to restore to an **Express** edition of SQL Server, which is **limited to 10 GB** (SQL Server 2008 R2 and newer). You cannot restore a database exceeding 10 GB to an Express edition

Comment: It seem your database crossed size limit.


Have a look on this very nice article as per your database edition.

[link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=SQL.105).aspx)

Comment: hi, But the empty database backup size is 160MB

Comment: But the **database size** (not the *backup size*) is over 10 GB as you said yourself.... you **cannot** restore a database that ends up being **more than 10 GB in size** to an Express edition.